# Customize Date Text to show 'tomorrow' in CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter

Basically, I have a CupertinoDatePicker widget, the maximum date is set to the next day i.e `now.day+1` , it shows the day, month and day i.e `Web, Feb 17` , how can I customize the text to show `Tomorrow`.

This is what I want to recreate

[image]

This is what I have currently

[image]

Below is the code for the Cupertino Date Picker widget

```
final now = DateTime.now();
CupertinoDatePicker(
    initialDateTime: now,
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
      print(newdate);
    },
    use24hFormat: true,
    maximumDate: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 2),
    minimumDate: now,
//    minuteInterval: 1,
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
  )
```

Comment: I don't see a way to customize it like this without modifying the library code.  You might want to check out CupertinoPicker, which is content agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you'd have to copy and modify the library code to do this.

Looks like this is set in the `_buildMediumDatePicker` method of the library code. You can find it by whatever the shortcut in your IDE is to view source code.

```
          final String dateText = rangeStart == DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
            ? localizations.todayLabel
            : localizations.datePickerMediumDate(rangeStart);

          return itemPositioningBuilder(
            context,
            Text(dateText, style: _themeTextStyle(context)),
          );
        },
```

So you would copy the code from the `date_picker.dart` library file into your project, rename (by refactoring) the `CupertinoDatePicker` to something like `MyCupertinoDatePicker` in your local code. You'll have to rename a couple other objects in that file to clear the errors.

Then modify that portion to this

```
          final String dateText =
              rangeStart == DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
                  ? localizations.todayLabel
                  : rangeStart == DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1)
                      ? 'Tomorrow'
                      : localizations.datePickerMediumDate(rangeStart);
```

I just tried it, it works.

Comment: Hi Loren.A , how can I copy the library file into my project

Comment: Navigate to the source code of the date picker. On Mac (VS Code or Android Studio) you would `command + click` on `CupertinoDatePicker`. Not sure on PC but probably `control + click`. That will take you to `date_picker.dart` Flutter source code file. Select all and copy it into a new file in your project then proceed like I described in my answer.